# FreeFileSync C++ error: 'byte' is not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build open source program and getting this error:

```
$ make
mkdir -p ../Obj/FFS_GCC_Make_Release/ffs/src/base/
g++ -std=c++17 -pipe -DWXINTL_NO_GETTEXT_MACRO -I../.. -I../../zenXml -include "zen/i18n.h" -include "zen/warn_static.h" -Wall -Wfatal-errors -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wswitch-enum -Wcast-align -Wshadow -Wnon-virtual-dtor -O3 -DNDEBUG `wx-config --cxxflags --debug=no` -pthread `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0` -c base/algorithm.cpp -o ../Obj/FFS_GCC_Make_Release/ffs/src/base/algorithm.o
In file included from base/../fs/abstract.h:13:0,
                 from base/structures.h:14,
                 from base/file_hierarchy.h:20,
                 from base/algorithm.h:11,
                 from base/algorithm.cpp:7:
../../zen/serialize.h:35:45: error: ‘byte’ is not a member of ‘std’
     using value_type     = std::vector<std::byte>::value_type;
                                             ^~~~
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
Makefile:108: recipe for target '../Obj/FFS_GCC_Make_Release/ffs/src/base/algorithm.o' failed
make: *** [../Obj/FFS_GCC_Make_Release/ffs/src/base/algorithm.o] Error 1
```

This source file contains `#include <cstdint>`

Here is a problem part of code: 
`using value_type = std::vector<std::byte>::value_type;`

How to reproduce: Download FreeFileSync source from official website, unpack

```
cd FreeFileSync_10.4_Source\FreeFileSync\Source
make
```

gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) under Windows Subsystem for Linux

Comment: It would be helpful to see which open source program you are compiling, maybe it is a known problem.

Comment: Try `#include <cstddef>`.

Comment: Assuming you have included `cstddef`, then add `-std=c++17` to the compiler invocation.

Comment: Voted to close as **lacking a reproducible example**.

Answer (score 2):

Add `#include <cstddef>` into serialize.h and ring_buffer.h

```
cd ../../zen/
grep -q -F '<cstddef>' serialize.h || sed -i '1s/^/#include <cstddef>\n/' serialize.h
grep -q -F '<cstddef>' ring_buffer.h || sed -i '1s/^/#include <cstddef>\n/' ring_buffer.h
```

Comment: Encountered this on CentOS 7 when building FreeFileSync 10.9. After some hacks to get gcc 7.3.1 (from SCL), these insertions enabled me to continue compiling.

Comment: For Windows C++ developers using Visual C++: On Windows, I had this same issue and I had to instal the latest version of my compiler(Visual Studio), and upgrade it to VS 2017, and change project settings to support C++ 17 standard, to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

std::byte is implemented since C++17. You may check your compiler version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `_HAS_STD_BYTE=1` in compile-definitions
use CMake to organize projects, you can do it this way:

```
add_compile_definitions(_HAS_STD_BYTE=1)
```